# Issue in dropping and creating a table with large number of columns in SYBASE ASE

Tags: sql, sap-ase

In our firm we have a table with around 150 columns (for some reason) in Sybase ASE 12.5
When we try to create this table in the first place, we get a usual warning message: "Warning: Row size (XXXX bytes) could exceed row size limit, which is 1962 bytes.", but the table still gets created.

**Now, when we try to drop this table and recreate it, it gives "Object already exists" error. But when we try to select anything from the table, we get "Object does not exists" error.**

The weird thing is, when I check the table in **sysobjects** it shows that it is present there. The entries are present even in **syscolumns**.

But when I again try to drop it, I again see "Object does not exists" error.
Any idea why it might be happening? Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How did you drop the table ? if you still can see it in sysobjects and syscolumns then I can't think of something other than some internal corruption .. was the drop table command successfull ?

have you tried running :

```
dbcc checkcatalog (<database_name>) ?
```